# spring mongodb: Unable to get document by id - Parameter does not have a name

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Here my related code:

```
Optional<Resource> resource = resourceMongoRepository.findById("65df60edbd43c107768b6191");
```

I'm getting:

> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Parameter org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter@c946e82b does not have a name

My repository is:

```java
public interface ResourceMongoRespository
    extends MongoRepository<Resource, String> {

}
```

Related mongo generated query log:

> DEBUG 189104 --- [tContainer#0-24] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : findOne using query: { "_id" : "65df60edbd43c107768b6191"} fields: Document{{}} for class: class net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.infrastructure.model.Resource in collection: resource

Into my mongosh:

```
test> db.resource.find({"_id" : ObjectId("65df60edbd43c107768b6191")});
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('65df60edbd43c107768b6191'),
    resourceId: Binary.createFromBase64('MkpJzQuAUBwhFCqfXjT4ow==', 3),
    resourceLocation: { location: '1c50800b-cd49-4a32-a3f8-345e9f2a1421', type: 'S3' },
    documentState: 'PENDING',
    _class: 'net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.infrastructure.model.Resource'
  }
]
```

I write fill caused by:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Parameter org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter@7627f000 does not have a name
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:49) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.extractInvocationArguments(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:301) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:273) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:98) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:519) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:487) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$DefaultConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2366) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2175) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1941) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:626) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:544) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:522) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:487) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:423) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:419) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:119) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:3278) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2874) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:2536) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:817) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findById(SimpleMongoRepository.java:127) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy57.findById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.infrastructure.repository.DocumentPersistenceOperations.get(DocumentPersistenceOperations.java:50) ~[infrastructure-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.application.document.pushed.PushedDocumentUseCase.consolidate(PushedDocumentUseCase.java:14) ~[application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.presentation.backoffice.rest.sqs.SQSS3CreatedNotificationService.listen(SQSS3CreatedNotificationService.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:169) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with Spring not being able to identify the fields in some object, I presume that will be that `Resource` object. Most probably it cannot identify the name of the parameters for the constructor in place.

You can put a breakpoint in that class `PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider` and see exactly the field that it is trying to map.

Posible solutions are:

- Add a no args constructor to that class
- For immutable objects, migrate them to a Java Records
- If the problem is with the String value, wrap it in an object (e.g. a record)